# Android - How to get ETA from Google Maps App Intent? (Or Waze?)

Tags: google-maps, android-intent, android-service, android-location

I'm working on android app witch will navigate to a place and do some stuff based on the ETA.

I don't want to deal with navigation at all and this is why i use an Intent to open Google Maps App.

Is there any way i can run a service to get the ETA from Google Maps App?

Can i do it with Waze or any other navigation app?

If not, 
what do you think about running a service wich will get ETA from Google Maps API every few minutes?

Thanks for you time.
Yirmi.

Comment: I think your services could call The Google Directions API from time to time to estimate the real ETA... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Thanks, thats ok, but i want to get the same ETA as Google Maps App is showing the user.

Comment: You can perhaps have a look at the TomTom NavApp SDK:
http://developer.tomtom.com/products/bridge/develop#navigation_apis

There is an EtaListener:
https://bridge-files.tomtom.com/developer/sdk/docs/navappsdk_api6/javadoc/com/tomtom/navapp/Trip.EtaListener.html