# Is there a way to get ETA from the google maps app in android via intent or broadcast-receiver?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an android app that needs to open google maps with an intent to navigate to a location, and then poll the ETA from navigation and use it to update the app. I've seen folks try to do this before in posts such as [this question from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322856/android-how-to-get-eta-from-google-maps-app-intent-or-waze)

however it's been several years so I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this now or if google maps listens to any intent filters that might be useful (perhaps with broadcast-receiver?)

I've looked through the [relevant docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#uriencoding) on the intents that you can send to google maps, and many of them return useful data, but they all seem to want to initiate navigation, as opposed to just query information about existing navigation. I'm assuming if I send such an intent after initiating navigation, they will restart the navigation itself which would induce unnecessary latency and be disruptive to the user.

Comment: No. But you can use [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) to get ETA via HTTP request in your application.

Comment: True, but there's no guarantee that the directions given to me by the API are the same as the ones I am currently following on my device, correct? Furthermore, this seems very inefficient as every API call is going to re-plan the entire route, as opposed to just being able to grab the current ETA

Comment: You can obtain entire route via Directions API once at start and don't request it again until the end of the route. And ETA can be estimated locally based on current location/speed/traffic etc. Anyway, there is no possibilities to get ETA from Google Maps application.